# Java: HTTPS запросы с сертификатами используя HttpClient (двусторонняя аутентификация)

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

Нужно отправлять GET-запросы на сервер через **HTTPS**. Для этих целей используется `Apache HttpClient 3.1.0`

Проблема заключается в том, что серверу требуется сертификат (двусторонняя аутентификация). Мне предоставили два файла: `client.cert.pem` и `client.key.pem`, из которых я получил `keystore.jks` и `keystore.p12` при помощи keytool и openssl.

Использую `curl` я успешно получаю данные с сервера

```
curl --cert client.cert.pem --key client.key.pem ...
```

Но в коде мне не удается правильно передать сертификат.

Изучив множество примеров в интернете я при пришел к такому коду:

```
final char[] JKS_PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(
    new File("ssl/keystore.jks"), JKS_PASSWORD, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();

HttpClient httpsClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
HttpResponse rResponse = httpsClient.execute(new HttpGet(MY_URL));
```

В этом случае у я получаю исключение:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
```

Если же использовать `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`:

```
...

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        sslContext,
        new String[] { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" },
        null,
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());


HttpClient httpsClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();
HttpResponse rResponse = httpsClient.execute(new HttpGet(MY_URL));
```

Выбрасывается:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Я явно что то напутал, но не могу понять что. Любая помощь приветствуется!

Comment: а не хотите импортировать сертификат ваш в keytool ?

Comment: на данном этапе меня любое решение утроит. я импортировал, но не знаю как это использовать. вообще хотелось бы на лету использовать сертификат

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть мобильное приложение под андроид, которое использует свои CA для проверки цепочки сертификатов. Попробуй взять отсюда часть кода или алгоритм. Оно конечно не для апач-клиента. Но, думаю, что-то общее выделить можно. перед отправкой запроса я вызываю

```
....
SSLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(MakeOWN_CASocketFactory());
....
 
SSLSocketFactory MakeOWN_CASocketFactory() {
        if (!useOwnCAForTLS || !serverURI.contains("DOMAIN.LOCAL")) return null;
        if (sslContext == null) {
            try {
                Debug("SocketFactoryOWN_CA(): Получаем локальное хранилище...");
                KeyStore localTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                InputStream rawRes = settingsContext.get().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.OWN_CA_root_ca);
                Debug("SocketFactoryOWN_CA():Загружаем локальное хранилище корневых сертификатов");
                localTrustStore.load(rawRes, "PASSWORD_THERE".toCharArray());
                trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                trustManagerFactory.init(localTrustStore);
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                Debug("SocketFactoryOWN_CA(): формируем SSL-контекст");
                sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

                return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug("loadOWN_CATrustStore(): Ошибка: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug("loadOWN_CATrustStore(): Ошибка: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return (localSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
String keyPhrase = "your_key_there";

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_cert"), keyPhrase
  .toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyPhrase.toCharArray()).build();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("your_url_there");

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: так я тоже пробовал, тот же экспешн: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;`

Comment: @Aray Добавь зависимость https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3

Comment: я уже использую эту библиотеку. обычные запросы нормально уходят. не могу прикрутить сертификаты для авторизации

Comment: в кейстор надо поместить все корневые и промежуточные сертификаты из цепочки сертификации которые участвуют в процессе, как на клиенте так и на сервере.